# Division by a variable during implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

In my textbook the author explains *implicit differentiation*. As example he uses a circle function:
$$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$
$$2x + 2yy' = 0$$
$$y' = \frac{-x}{y}$$
I don't like the third step. He divides by $y$, but doesn't mention that he checks that it is never zero. Do you have in a similar situation show that some variable is *never zero* or at least when it's zero the *derivative doesn't exist*?

Because I think I can place a circle in such way that it has $y$ equal zero and has a definite derivative at the same time.

Comment: When $y=0$ the *tangent* is vertical and the *derivative*...

Comment: And you can indeed place a circle so that $y=0$ and the derivative exists there, but not *this* circle. For the other circle, you would be dividing by something else that *is* zero, like maybe $(y-y_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with implicit differentiation is there are some, well, *implicit* assumptions under it.

You have some function $F(x,y)$ and an equatio $F(x,y)=0$. In your case, the function is $x^2+y^2-r^2$. Now, by the implicit function theorem, for a neighborhood of a point $(x_0,y_0)$ at which $\frac{dF}{dy}\neq 0$, you can find a function $y=y(x)$ such that on the neighborhood, you have $F(x,y(x))=0$.

Now, if you want do see what the derivative of this function is, you simply derive $F(x,y(x))=0$ by $x$ and get $\frac{dF}{dx} + \frac{dF}{dy}\cdot y'(x) = 0$ and extract the calue of $y(x)$.

However, this all hangs on one important point: the point $(x_0,y_0)$, around which you must be able to express $y$ as a function of $x$. As you correctly noticed, at $y=0$, this cannot be done. Therefore, the example you gave only holds for $y\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

All sorts of things are possible - however there is an important intuition which you may lose if you get over worried about infinities.

The circle is a smooth curve - it clearly has a tangent at each point. What has gone wrong with finding the tangent is not anything to do with the circle - it involves the choice of co-ordinates. There ought to be some way, intrinsic to the circle, to define the tangent. Further work with curves and surfaces formalises this intuition. One might want, for example, to choose different co-ordinates for different parts of the circle to avoid the problem, and then find a way of patching them together - in such a way we can define a manifold.

So this apparently simple problem leads naturally into some much deeper mathematics.